# Convert complex nested JSON to csv using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I got a complex nested JSON file and I need to convert it completely, but my code can only convert part of the information,
How can I modify my code, or do you guys have a better code?

my json file

```
import csv
import json
import sys
import codecs

def trans(path):
    jsonData = codecs.open('H://14.json', 'r', 'utf-8')
    # csvfile = open(path+'.csv', 'w') 
    # csvfile = open(path+'.csv', 'wb') 
    csvfile = open('H://11.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')  
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    flag = True
    for line in jsonData:
        dic = json.loads(line)
        if flag:
            keys = list(dic.keys())
            print(keys)
            writer.writerow(keys)
            flag = False
        writer.writerow(list(dic.values()))
    jsonData.close()
    csvfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path=str(sys.argv[0])
    print(path)
    trans(path)
```

my json file

```
{"id":"aa","sex":"male","name":[{"Fn":"jeri","Ln":"teri"}],"age":45,"info":[{"address":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"},"start_date":"2001-09","title":{"name":"Doctor","Exp":"head"},"year":"2001","month":"05"}],"other":null,"Hobby":[{"smoking":null,"gamble":null}],"connect":[{"phone":"123456789","email":"info@gmail.com"}],"Education":"MBA","School":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"}}
{"id":"aa","sex":"female","name":[{"Fn":"lo","Ln":"li"}],"age":34,"info":[{"address":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"},"start_date":"2008-11","title":{"name":"Doctor","Exp":"hand"},"year":"2008","month":"02"}],"other":null,"Hobby":[{"smoking":null,"gamble":null}],"connect":[{"phone":"123456789","email":"info@gmail.com"}],"Education":"MBA","School":{"State":"NY","City":"new york"}}
```

It only converts part of the information, 'name''info''Hobby''connect''School' these information are not converted,I need to convert all information completely,

Comment: Is there any reason that you are not using `pandas`? Also, it seems your file is not a correct json file, it needs to be started with `[` and ends with `]` and each line (in your case) should be separated by `,`

Comment: csv and nested data structures dont go along well. CSV is striclty flat. Anything nested and you need to include the whole nested thing as string in that field or go for a relational apporach like in sql.

Comment: You need to show what your expected output CSV format is for that data. A number of the fields are lists, how should these be flattened, or do you need multiple columns (e.g. one for each hobby?)

Comment: Are you trying to create a generic JSON to CSV convertor, or is this a fixed format?

Comment: I need to fully flatten the json in the example and convert it to csv, so I need code that fits my json file, either generic or fixed，@Martin Evans

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below function to treat each `dic`. It will flatten the dict by recursive calls until there is no dict or list in the values. In order to avoid issues with 2 `keys` having the same name, I concatenate with the previous level.
**WARNING**: it is based on your format so if you have lists with more than one element in the middle, it will only take care of the first element.

```py
def flatten_dict(input_dict, result = None):
    result = result or {}
    for key, value in input_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            current_dict = {key+"_"+k: v for k, v in value[0].items()}
            flatten_dict(current_dict, result)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            current_dict = {key+"_"+k: v for k, v in value.items()}
            flatten_dict(current_dict, result)
        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

Then apply this function on each dic, transform to Dataframe and save as CSV.

```py
res = []
for line in jsonData:
    dic = json.loads(line)
    res.append(flatten_dict(dic))
res_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
res_df.to_csv("result.csv")
```

Result:
[image]